# "__text" in angular css class name

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular

I was reading an angular code and saw a div with cssClass = "show-more-items__text". In the .less file, I can see the definition for "show-more-items" but no class definition for "show-more-items__text". I am not sure what does "__text" mean?

```
<span class="show-more-items__text">sample string</span>
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't have to *mean* anything

Comment: so what would be the css class for this span ?

Comment: What do you mean? The element's classList is obviously `['show-more-items__text']`. There's no requirement for an element's `class` attribute to be used anywhere. It could be `<span class="show-more-items__text some-other-class and-another-one-that-is-never-used hey-look-at-that-more-classes">`

Comment: what I meant is that this 'show-more-items__text' class is never defined in any css. was wondering if there is any purpose to use a css class which has no definition

Comment: Could require fewer code changes if you wanted to target that element at a later date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they are using BEM notation. https://bem.info/

It's just a naming convention.

Comment: Thank you, very nice reference, I didn't know about it